# How to prove $\mu(X \cup Y) \geq \mu(X) +\mu(Y) $ for this measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue outer measure I want to prove $\mu(X \cup Y) = \mu(X) +\mu(Y) $ so far I have used properties of this measure to show $\mu(X \cup Y) \leq \mu(X) +\mu(Y) $ so what remains is to show $\mu(X \cup Y) \geq \mu(X) +\mu(Y) $ however I am unsure how to proceed. All I have that I have yet to use is that $X,Y$ are subsets of real numbers and that they are disjoint and non empty.

Any help??

Comment: What is the definition you are using? The proof almost certainly depends on the initial choice of axioms (I imagine)

Comment: This question appeared also today in another question. Anyway, the Legesgue outer measure is NOT additive.

Comment: Sorry I forgot a crucial piece of info . Both X and Y and disjoint intervals. Could you help me now please @PaoloLeonetti

Comment: @RyanS additivity is, by definition, on disjoint sets.. Then, no, you can find disjoint subsets $X,Y$ for which $\mu(X\cup Y)<\mu(X)+\mu(Y)$.

Comment: I believe $X$ and $Y$ here should be positevely separated sets and you're trying to prove that the Lebesgue measure is a metric measure

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$X\cup Y=(X\backslash Y)\sqcup(X\cap Y)\sqcup (Y\backslash X),$$

where $A\sqcup B$ denote the disjoint union of $A\cup B$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how this helps can you elaborate?